# Python3 crash when creating HDF5 file via H5Py

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, h5py

I'm working to migrate code from an existing, working Python 2.7 application into Python 3.  This is running on Windows 7, and using the Anaconda distribution.

In that code, I generate HDF5 files using H5Py and NumPy.  The code works fine in Python 2.7, but in Python 3.4 (H5Py 2.5) the code segfaults on `h5.create_dataset()`.

Below is my minimum, replicating test case:

```
import h5py
import numpy
import tempfile

data = [(1,2,3) for x in range(100)]
dtypes=[('one',numpy.dtype(int),),('two',numpy.dtype(int),), ('three',numpy.dtype(int),)]

tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
filename = tmp.name
h5 = None
try:
    with h5py.File(filename,'w') as h5:
        print('Creating NumPY array')
        z = numpy.array(data, dtype=dtypes)

        print('Creating dataset')
        dset = h5.create_dataset('test', data=z) #python crashes here.
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    if h5:
        h5.close()

print('Python never reaches here.')
```

If I discard the `dtypes`, for the NumPy array, then the code works.  But I require the `dtype` settings (in my full application, this array is dynamically generated based on the data at hand).

ie, If I change

```
z = numpy.array(data, dtype=dtypes)
```

to

```
z = numpy.array(data)
```

The code works.

I've attempted to encode the `dtype` type names (ie, 'one', 'two', 'three'), in various ways, thinking maybe the unicode in Py3 strings was the problem.  Instead, NumPy produced exceptions and failed to create the data array.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong.  Can someone help me out here?

Comment: I don't have h5py right now so I'm afraid I can't test your script. What happen if you create first the dataset with no data, and then fill it? `dset = h5.create_dataset('test', shape=z.shape, dtype=z.dtype); dset[:] = z`

Comment: Interesting.  That moves the crash to the `dset[:] = z` call.  However, the same symptom remains: if I don't set the dtype on the numpy array, everything is good.

Perhaps I'm setting up the dtype array incorrectly.  Time to do some more reading.

Comment: I tried your script: it perfectly works on my workstation: Windows 7 64 bits, h5py 2.5.0, numpy 1.9.2, Python 3.4.3, with the distribution WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.5.

Comment: I observe the same using WinPython.  Which leads me down the rabbit hole to [this github issue](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/593).  Looks like the official Anaconda distribution is currently broken for H5Py.  Peachy.  thank you for your help on this!

Answer (score 0):

The cause appears due to a problem in the Windows 64-bit Anaconda 2.3.0 for Python 3.4, as per https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/593.

Other distributions (such as WinPython, or other distributions of Anaconda) appear to work fine.